# How to make other element in scroll adjust when an item has a child?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Hello, any advice how to make 'obj#2' move down or adjust when for example obj#1 has a childs?

for the mean time some child or the 1st child of Object#1 is overlapping with Obj#2.

goal is:

```
 obj#1
   child0
   child1
   child2
 obj#2 <-----
```

my hierarchy setup is:

scroll_view <---scrollrect,mask
  content <---vertical layout group, content size fitter
    [[obj#1]]
      sub_content<--- vertical layout group, content size fitter
       [[obj#1 child0]]
       [[obj#1 child1]]
    [[obj#2]]
    so on...

I've played around with the settings/options and searched for a video tutorial but most of the one I get are single elements list in scroll view only.

Thank you for reading. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Content Size Fitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html) on **obj#1** with Vertical fitting, but you should add [Layout Element](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/script-LayoutElement.html) to you child’s(**child0, child1, child2**) and setup preferred height. But you setup must be identical, if you setup `Min Height` in Layout Element, use `Vertical Fit - Minimum`, or `Preferred`, when use `Preferred Width`

EDIT: oh, I see you use Content Size Fitter, but if you haven’t Layout Element component on childs, Content Size Fitter can works unpredictably. And, try to add Vertical Layout group on Scroll View, this may help to control vertical position of the elements according to the size

Comment: I will try and continue exploring more options, thank you @Nikel !  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @AgentBurger please)